# DataTables javascript could not be applied to repeating tables

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, datatables

I have a table function (table_view.php)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="test_coding_rosa/table_design2.css">


    </head>

<body>


<?php
$row_id="";
if($_GET['page']==1 || isset($_GET['page'])==false){
    $row_id=1;
}elseif (isset($_GET['page']) && $_GET['page']>1) {
    $row_id=($_GET['page']-1)."1";
}

$doc = JFactory::getDocument();

$doc->addScript('http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js');
$doc->addScript('http://datatables.net/download/build/nightly/jquery.dataTables.js');

$doc->addScriptDeclaration('
    jQuery(document).ready( function () {
        jQuery("#main-table").DataTable();
    });
');


?>
<h1><?php echo $this->title ?></h1>

<table id="main-table" border="<?php echo $this->tableBorder ?>" class="display" <?php if(!empty($this->tableWidth)) echo 'width="'.$this->tableWidth.'"';?> >
<thead>
  <?php 
  if(!$this->hideHeaderTable)
  {

      if($_GET['t']!='maklumat_ringkas'){
      echo "<tr><th width='10px'>Bil</th>";
      }


      foreach($this->tableData[0] as $key=>$tableHeader)
      {
          ?>
        <th width="<?php echo $this->tableData[1][$key] ?>" scope="col"><?php echo $this->tableData[0][$key] ?></th>
        <?php
      }
      ?>
      </tr>
      </thead>
  <?php
  }


  $lenData = count($this->tableData);

  for ($j=3;$j < $lenData; ++$j)
  {
      ?>
      <tbody>
      <tr class="centertable" <?php if($j % 2==1) echo 'bgcolor="#EFF4FB"'?>><?php if($_GET['t']!='maklumat_ringkas'){echo "<td>".$row_id++."</td>";}?>
          <?php 
          foreach($this->tableData[0] as $key=>$tableHeader)
          {
              ?>
            <td width="<?php echo $this->tableData[1][$key] ?>" <?php echo $this->tableData[2][$key] ?>><?php echo stripslashes($this->tableData[$j][$key]) ?></td>
            <?php
          }
          ?>
      </tr>
      </tbody>
      <?php
  }

  ?>

</table>
</body>
</html>
```

This table_view.php is the default table for all data in the site. As you can see in the photo below, there are multiple tables being called from table_view.php.

The problem here is, I wanted to use DataTables.net to include the pagination of the tables. However, only the first table has been successfully implemented with DataTables.net plugin.

[image]

How can I implement it on all of the tables? Since all the tables are being called from the same function file (table_view.php), the table id is the same.

UPDATED declaration

```
$doc = JFactory::getDocument();

$doc->addScriptDeclaration(" 
    jQuery('[id='main-table']').each(function(i,e) {
    var id=jQuery(this).attr('id');
    jQuery(this).attr('id', id+'_'+i);
    jQuery(this).addClass('datatable-identifier');
}); ");

$doc->addScript('http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js');
$doc->addScript('http://datatables.net/download/build/nightly/jquery.dataTables.js');



$doc->addScriptDeclaration('
    jQuery(document).ready( function () {
    jQuery(".datatable-identifier").dataTable();
} );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having multiple elements with the same `id` is a very bad habit :) You should really try to avoid it. Though HTML is forgiving, it results as you see in all kind of problems when trying to access elements in javascript.

If it is impossible to avoid, you could run the following function before calling `dataTable()` :

```js
jQuery('[id="main-table"]').each(function(i,e) {
    var id=jQuery(this).attr('id');
    jQuery(this).attr('id', id+'_'+i);
    jQuery(this).addClass('datatable-identifier');
});
```

This will rename the table id's to `main-table_1`, `main-table_2` and so on. The class `datatable-identifier` is just a dummy class used when initializing the dataTables, change your code to :

```
jQuery(document).ready( function () {
   jQuery(".datatable-identifier").dataTable();
});
```

Comment: This was what I had in mind. A code that assigns a different id to the table everytime it loops through. But i've tried declaring the function before calling datatable() as you said. But it's not working. i"ve put it right below $doc = JFactory::getDocument();

Comment: error on the console stated "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier". The code is updated in my question above. But however, I actually managed to find a work around by initializing using table class selector instead of table id. But, somehow, it works only on certain type of user groups.

Comment: @mfmz, have made this fiddle -> http://jsfiddle.net/EHUGe/ "3 (data) tables with id="main-table" example", eg the sample from above. Sry, cannot reproduce the syntax error.

Comment: Oh, you miss `');` after the last `$doc->addScriptDeclaration('`, if it is not a copy paste typo